# How to add up a certain range of numbers

Tags: python, numbers

I am new to python. I was trying to add up the following code's result together. I tried sum() function, however, It didn't work out. Can someone help me with it, please? Thank you!

I want to add all these numbers together and print out them:011235813213455891442333776109871597

```
def fib(n):
    a,b = 0,1
    while a <n:
        print(a,end='')
        a,b=b,a+b
    print()

fib(2000)
```

Comment: Are you trying to print the Fibonacci Series?

Comment: Yes, and also I wanted to know how to add numbers together based on the code I provided above. Thanks!

Comment: So are you trying to add or are you trying to print? Describe your idea in details.

Comment: I have added an answer using two approaches. Hope it helps

Comment: @user12174248 So what's the problem? What is the difference to compare with your code?

Comment: @user12174248 I hope you are able to understand the changes i made to your approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Fibonacci Series, you can try this:

```
def fib(n):
    l = [0, 1]
    while True:
        if len(l) < n:
            l.append(l[-1] + l[-2])
        else:
            break
    print(l)
fib(8)
```

l[-1] represents the last element of the list 'l' and l[-2] represents the second last element of the list 'l'

You can also try a slightly modified version of you code:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b, series_length = 0, 1, 0
    while series_length < n:
        print(a)
        a, b = b, a + b
        series_length += 1
fib(5)
```